# Why do I get this error (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED after ajax request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

In my localhost it works fine, but on hosting I get this error

> (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

What does this error mean and how can I solve this problem? This is a Laravel/vue project.

Code of ajax request:

```
var firstHalf =  this.menu.slice(0, 21);
var secondHalf =  this.menu.slice(21);
var result = [firstHalf,secondHalf];
this.isLoading = true;
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    let statusCode = 200;
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/admin/menu/addMenu/",
        header: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        },
        params: {
            menu: result[i],
            startDate: this.selectedDate,
            order: i + 1
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("ajax")
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response);
        if (i+1>= result.length) {
            this.message = response.data.message;
            this.modalShow = true;
            this.isLoading = false;
                return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd start ... as I always do in cases like this ... by examining the web-browser's "programmer" tracing screens.  (Every browser has them, somewhere.)  ***Look*** at what is actually being sent by the client, HTTP headers and all, and likewise ***look*** at what the host is sending in response.  Then, check the host-side error logs to see if PHP is throwing an exception message.  *(PHP is notorious for "let's log a message and just keep going," but maybe you'll see an actual failure which might explain what you're seeing.)*  In my experience, you've got to ***look*** at the exchanges.

Comment: You should add a `.catch(err => { /* code to debug */ })` on your axios request and `console.log(err)` to see what is the error thrown by the server.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following:

```js
var verifyIdentity = formData.get('verify_identity')

if(verifyIdentity && verifyIdentity.size === 0){
    formData.delete('verify_identity')
}
```

Basically saying, if there is a file type attribute, but it is not filled out (meaning you never actually picked the file to submit), just remove it from form data.

It's a tad different example as I don't see what you're actually submitting, but I noticed the issue on my part was due to the `type="file"` input fields.