# jQuery AJAX fail with files in form request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an issue with jQuery AJAX call on my Laravel application. It fails when using `type="file"` in the form.

I can't reproduce the issue locally, it happens on prod server only.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: $(this).attr("method"),
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    ...
```

The error I get is:

> POST ... net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

No errors in Laravel logs, if I dump error in error callback there is only a message "error", so nothing helpful there.

What might be the issue?

Comment: would you try this command `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: It has no effect. It fails on JS side, composer is PHP

Comment: similar problem for  `laravel + vue` ..[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859186/why-do-i-get-this-error-failed-neterr-connection-closed-after-ajax-request)... also am looking for the answer..

Comment: Is your host on https?

Comment: Could it be your data? `FormData()` is suppose to be initialized first, then be appended to, like `var fd = new FormData(); fd.append('mykey', 'myvalue');`

Comment: It is initialized with `this` which is basically the form. I am only appending the token, and I suppose if it was up to data then local would fail as well?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the server freaks out if you set file type and try to submit a form without actually submitting the actual file. In that case the field comes up as having name `""` and size `0`.

Doing this worked like a charm:

```js
var verifyIdentity = formData.get('verify_identity')

if(verifyIdentity && verifyIdentity.size === 0){
    formData.delete('verify_identity')
}
```